# I've clarified my question about mondegreens; can we re-open it? [resolved]

Tags: support, status-completed

> Update: the question has been re-opened and has started getting answers. Thanks to everyone for your votes.

Requesting votes to remove the hold tag for [this question I had posted](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/365365/55623).

I have made the required edits to bring clarity as well to bring it within the scope of the forum. It's already got 2 re-open votes, it just needs 3 more.